# Are there any common phrases in the English language that use metric units of measurement?

Tags: expressions, measuring-units

We've got things like 'inch closer' or 'miss by miles' but nothing common that uses the metric system as far as I know.

Comment: You can have a _ton_ of something, which is at least possibly metric. And of course, if you use ‘metric’ in the wider sense as basically referring to SI units, you can also include time values such as _second_, which are quite common in expressions (“I don’t believe it for a second!”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't want to be pedantic, but isn't _tonne_ considered metric rather than the long or short _ton_ ? And yes, second can be considered since the imperial units were defined in the British _Weights and Measures Act_ of 1824, so by definition they had no units for time. Thanks !

Comment: @Janus Here in the UK, "Ton" is imperial. You'd have to say "tonne" or "metric ton" for the metric version. "Second" is *the* metric/SI unit of time (along with multiples of seconds like kilosecond etc but no other common time units) but it's also imperial so doesn't really answer.

Comment: "Burning calories" works.

Comment: @Rupe, if you consider former-SI units as "metric".

Comment: @Jon, calorie is definitely a metric unit. SI and metric do not mean the same thing, the former set of units is a subset of the latter.

Comment: @Rupe I would rather say that ‘ton’ on its own is entirely meaningless (in the UK, _ton_ [may not be used for trade at all, except as a supplementary indication](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1985/72#commentary-c1337092)). It can equally well refer to a metric, imperial, freight, displacement, long, short, gross, net, or register ton. That is why I wrote that it is at least _possibly_ metric, depending on which ton you’re talking about. A _tonne_ is unequivocally metric, but not used in the idiom.

Comment: @Janus. I'm confused, "ton" is "entirely meaningless" but you go on to discuss its meaning! And whether or not the law allows one to use it in certain situations has little to do with its *meaning* (any more than SI plumping for joule rather than calorie changes the meaning of the latter). I don't think the laws which enshrine the move to the metric system cover our *metaphorical* use of units like this. So I think, based on your list, you could well argue that "a ton of work" uses "ton" in a *generic* way. But I think you'd be hard pushed to argue that it's using a specifically metric unit.

Comment: @Rupe ‘Entirely meaningless’ was hyperbole. Obviously, it retains a basic meaning; but if you use ‘ton’ on its own, with no qualifying whatsoever, it does not necessarily refer to a long ton. I never argued that ‘ton’ was specifically metric; only that one of its definitions is metric, unlike ‘mile’ or ‘inch’, which have _no_ metric definitions whatsoever. In various idioms **all** these units of measurement are being used in a generic, non-specific sense, and you’d be equally hard pushed to argue that even the Imperial-only units are being used in a specifically Imperial sense.

Comment: @Jon. Exactly. I think what we're being asked for are phrases that use specifically metric units. Whether or not the ones which don't are in fact using the units in a specifically imperial sense is something of a red herring.

Comment: You can have a "metric sh*t-ton" of something, if that counts

Comment: A member of some group working as a spy for someone else is called a **mole**, even though he'll hardly be able to leak 6*10^23 bits of information. -- And if you are under *pressure* you may find relief in a **bar** (10^5 Pascal). -- :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of expressions using *second*, which is metric. Of course, here the fact that the unit predates the SI system is a strong influence.

*Gram* is beginning to replace *ounce*, *grain* and other small units in expressions where it would once have been used, so we can find people using "gram of sense", "gram of truth" etc.

*Calorie* appears in a few expressions related to health, diet and exercise and as such generally referring to a "large calorie" (kcal) rather than a "small calorie" (cal) since large calories are what are conventionally used by food. This unit used to be part of the metric system, and can be considered as part of it in conventional use, though it is no longer used in the SI and so you might decide not to include it as "metric" or not.

*Megahertz* is sometimes used to as a metonym for internet connection speeds and computing power. "Is someone taking all the megahertz?" might be a joking complaint by someone on a shared network, and there are variations of this:

[image]

We will no doubt begin to see more such expressions as young people increasingly don't learn the obsolete units, though the history of the language, and the fondness of the US for being quaint, will likely keep them in the language for some time. After all, we still have *farthing* and (rarely) even *sou* used to mean "very small amount of money" though increasingly the people using them may have never seen a farthing, or even know what a sou is.

Comment: "Metric" predates "SI" so I don't think it's right to restrict oneself to the latter if looking for phrases involving metric units. And "calorie" is definitely metric, even if the SI standard plumped for "joule".

Comment: Thank you ! That is very comprehensive ! I should have thought about '_gram of truth_' since that actually is a commonly used expression.

Comment: Would you not say that _gram_ is more likely replacing _grain_ than _ounce_ in ‘a gram of sense’, etc.? Both _grain_ and _ounce_ have been used in that sense for long, but _gram_ and _grain_ happen to sound the same, too.

Comment: @Rupe, *metric* is used of various systems, historically related to each other, including the SI system. As such, it is both used as a synonym for the SI system (which no longer contains calories) and more widely, so you certainly could exclude *calorie* from a given use of *metric*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet or really, it would be both gram and grain.

Comment: @Jon I disagree. Metric is (still) a superset of SI and calorie is a perfect example of that fact.

Comment: @Rupe so nobody ever uses the word *metric* as synonymous to *SI*? I remain unconvinced.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "gram of truth" in the UK, it'd still be "ounce" or "grain". But it makes sense that answers to this question might be regional to some extent.

Comment: @Rupe I'm asking from an Indian perspective, if that helps.

Comment: @Jon. Usually it doesn't matter, because SI is a proper subset. As you said, "metric" is used of various systems. "SI" is not, it is a strict list defined by committees. My point here is only that it is wrong to question whether "calories" is a metric unit on the basis of it not being an SI unit. The calorie is in CGS, and defined in terms of grams and degrees Celsius, what more could one ask of it?

Comment: Given Google Books has only 369 instances of [*a **gram** of truth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+gram+of+truth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), compared to 1,120,000 instances of [*a **grain** of truth*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+grain+of+truth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I suggest @RaunakS's claim that it's "commonly used" be [*taken with a **gram** of salt*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22taken+with+a+gram+of+salt%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (there are 30 of those).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hey, could be worse than a ratio of 1:3000. I admit, I mostly hear it on television and since _gram_ and _grain_ sound somewhat similar, it's highly probably I've misheard.

Comment: In gangsta culture kilos and grams are used as unit of dealing drugs. That's where expressions using metric, if any, might come from in the future.

Comment: @JoBedard Americans use the metric system when getting something right is important (with the exception of NASA, causing more than a few snafus), and drug-dealing is one of those cases. Conversely, cannabis is often sold by the ounce even in otherwise metric-using countries, perhaps suggesting that those who favour cannabis have a more laid-back and slightly nostalgic attitude than those who favour cocaine.

Comment: @RaunakS: My guess is all of those "grams of salt" were from native speakers being deliberately facetious. And if it weren't for your earlier comment, I'd have said the same about "grams of truth". But even if you misheard it every single time on tv, that implies many others would probably do the same. At least *some* of them will repeat it, and there either are or will eventually be people who never even knew the ***grain*** original. (So perhaps you're at the cutting edge of a newly-emerging idiomatic usage! :)

Comment: @ jon hanna Actually, according to the Urban dictionnary kilo and grams are supposed to be used in cocaine deals. I would not know directly, I never bought any though.

Comment: @JoBedard if you start a sentence with "Actually, according to the Urban dictionary", you may have a bad time ;) But yes, in this case that is true, I was comparing the use of ounces for cannabis with exactly that use of SI for cocaine.

Comment: @Fumblefinders: and some of those gram examples could *easily* be OCR errors for "grain".

Comment: @RaunakS  Do you have a 100 kilowatt smile yet?

Comment: "Megahertz is sometimes used to as a metonym for internet connection speeds" -- that might be metric but still horribly wrong.

Comment: @Raphael more often not horribly wrong as deliberately wrong for humourous effect.

Answer (score 1):

In Australian English we would say "It's only five kay's to the pub" or "Sydney to Brissie, about a thousand klicks"