# Preparing for metric dominance: alternatives to idioms using imperial units

Tags: idioms, measuring-units

Related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173805/are-there-any-common-phrases-in-the-english-language-that-use-metric-units-of-me), are there any metric *alternatives* to these idioms:

> 1. He **inches** closer to her.
>      a. meters? - *too far*
>      b. centimeters? - *too weird*
>      c. scoots? - *don't use units*
> 2. By then, she was **miles away** from him.
>      a. far away? - *again, don't use units*
>      b. kilometers away? - *maybe*
>      c. light-years away? - *probably better, preserving the hyperbole*
> 3. This is an amazing **foot-long** sandwich.
>      a. half-a-meter-long? - *not accurate*
>      b. dong-long? - *even less accurate. It rhymes, though*
>      c. about-a-third-of-a-meter-long? - *pretty accurate, but not very marketable*
> 4. I went **the whole nine yards**.
>      a. the whole 8.23 meters? - *...No*
>      b. all the way? - *again, don't use units*
> 5. **An ounce** of common sense is worth **a pound** of theory.
>      a. A gram/a tonne? - *preserve the weight comparison, but even more hyperbolic*
>      b. A little/a lot? - *again, don't use units*

Any suggestions? I mean, I've never seen any idioms using obsolete units like [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(length)), [furlong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furlong) or [league](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_(unit)), but I'm sure there were some when they were in common usage.

Comment: For most of the above, it looks like not using any units is a viable alternative.

Comment: This is why we still use words like _dozen, score, pair, triplet,_ and so on. Idioms get **more** popular when they use unusual words.

Comment: Yeah, but at least they're not under threat of obsolescence by the metric system :p.

Comment: English-speaking countries (except for the US) have used the metric system for decades and _inch, mile, pound, ounce, foot,_ and _yard_ seem to be apprehended most places, and used frequently enough.

Comment: The US customary measurements are not imperial units. This is a misnomer.

Comment: For now, yes, but in hundreds of years, when metric is used from here to the furthest colonies of humans across the galaxy, will they know what these idioms mean? Or the original meaning of the words?

Comment: "in hundreds of years, when metric is used from here to the furthest colonies of humans across the galaxy, will they know what these idioms mean? Or the original meaning of the words?" Yes, of course - in Italy they freely use "miles" for instance.  And in France "inches". It's a great question and as the answers reflect, the answer is "people keeping using sensible british units for idiomatic use."  Even in a million years.

Comment: Note too that we happen to be going through an unusual historical period of very strong government. (For say, 200 years or so.)  This will soon pass and people will go back to using normal sensible british units, as the whole world has for many thousands of years.  (It's worth remembering that Napoleon, as a key figure in "introduction in modern epoch to world of strong government", was key to the metric system.) Let's drink a pint on that!

Comment: @tchrist All of the units mentioned in the question are common to the American customary system and Imperial, with the same definitions. Also, the asker is in Indonesia, not the USA. As such, it seems possible that they actually do mean "Imperial" rather than "American customary".

Comment: @JoeBlow: I'd be careful about predicting what the world will or won't be doing in a million years.

Comment: Same here, in French we kept some old expressions based on old units not used anymore : - "Avoir les **coudées** franches", une coudée eq. a cubit - "Un voyage de **mille lieues** commence par un pas", milles lieues eq. a thousand leagues - "Ne pas bouger d'**un pouce**", un pouce eq. one inch - "poireauter **des lustres**", un lustre eq. a lustrum (5 years) etc.

Comment: "The metric system is the Tool of the Devil. My car gets 40 rods to the hogshead and that's the way I likes it." Although Grandpa Simpson probably meant 40 chains to the gill - 40 rd/hhd is spectacularly poor fuel economy.

Comment: Not to be picky, but I don't believe that light-years are actually a metric unit.

Comment: A foot-long sandwich is still (approximately) as long as my foot, regardless of the units of measure I use.

Comment: @adamv Congratulations on having foot-long feet, but unfortunately not everyone has imperial unit appendages :D

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question assumes that if metric is dominant, then we need alternatives for non-metric idioms.

But this is incorrect. We can still use whichever idioms we want.

There are plenty of phrases and idioms using obsolete terms. We understand the meaning without knowing their origin. No problem.

There are officially metric countries that sell TVs, monitors, shirts and trousers by the inch. Some people don't even realise they are imperial units. Vinyl records are also sold by the inch (e.g. 12") and boxing gloves by the ounce (e.g. 16 oz).

So why should idioms, figurative by their nature, and not subject to retail law, require non-imperial replacements?

As long as they're useful, understood and used, they'll be used. Their meanings will change too, but still, they'll be used.

Comment: In Germany, laws concerning advertisement are much stricter than most places in the world, but even *here*, the courts ruled that since the term "3,5" floppy disk" was not actually being used comparatively (e.g. "our disk is bigger/smaller than our competitor's") but as a class description, it did not constitute illegal advertisement. Likewise for monitors. If you want to compare your screen size to the one of a competitor, you have to give the measurements in metric units, but if you are simply referring to the general size class (15.4", 17", 20", 21", 24", 30" ,…) then you're fine.

Comment: And this is from a country that never even used those units in the first place.

Comment: Terminology *might* slowly change for a certain category of words that somewhat "consciously" refer to the unit, such as in "yard stick".

Comment: Despite me really looking for _alternatives_, I'm accepting this answer as it addresses the fundamental issue behind my question: No matter what happens to the imperial units, idioms will still use them. Top job.

Comment: @JörgWMittag in common in europe, AFAIK, in general we know approximate meaning of these units, thus a phrase `miles away` or `inches closer` is not confusing and is ok

Answer (score 16):

Be not afraid, in Russia we still use expressions that employ [long-passed away names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolete_Russian_units_of_measurement) of measurement units like **[versta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verst)**, sazhen and arshin.

For example, a lanky guy could be called "a versta of Kolomna", since centuries ago mile posts (actually, versta posts)  installed by the Tzar's decree along the road from Moscow to Kolomna were exceptionally high. A verst is surprisingly close to a kilometer in length, but you won't hear the word in a TV report. Still, it lives on in fixed expressions.

Wikipedia has [a section on the idiomatic expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolete_Russian_units_of_measurement#Idiomatic_expressions) keeping old Russian measurement units afloat.

An English-speaking person now and then uses the word **[fathom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fathom)** despite it being obsolete.

(correction: "near-obsolete" - according to a comment below, "NOAA in the United States still uses fathoms and feet on nautical charts").

Comment: Fathom may still be in use, but usually meaning the (obsolete) first meaning (Grasp, envelopment, control), instead of meaning a unit of measurement. If I ask an average person on an average road in Moscow, will they know what the original meaning of "versta" is?

Comment: Yes, they will know that it was a unit of measurement, but almost nobody will know its exact length, since it dropped out of use a century ago.

Comment: @StorymasterQ To fathom was originally to measure the depth of the ocean, e.g., with a plumb line. This is a long, slow process, involving lowering a rope at the end. It came to mean, figuratively, to understand something by a long, slow process. So the word "fathom" that we use today is the same word as the unit of measurement, just with a figurative, rather than literal, meaning.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - fathom does not necessarily imply slowly, but to understand thoroughly and accurately. The time a ship would most likely bother to plumb the depths would be in shallower waters, to make sure to avoid grounding / damaging the boat, or to navigate a known deeper course towards a harbour. In shallower waters it is not an especially slow process.

Comment: @AdamV True. Though one normally only uses "fathom" for reasonably difficult problems that do take a fairly long time to understand thoroughly and accurately.

Comment: Not obsolete. NOAA in the United States still uses fathoms and feet on nautical charts.

Answer (score 14):

In Australia we want "metric" starting with decimal currency (dollars) in 1966, and ending with Real Estate measurements in 1987. The bulk of the conversion occurred in the 1974 to 1978 period, where almost every measurement for legal purposes was required to be in SI units.

Having an English heritage and ingrained use of [Imperial measurements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units) meant that we often used expressions such as

- open the window an inch please.
- they live miles away.
- As you mention: an ounce of common sense is worth a pound of theory.
- Penny wise pound foolish

These terms are still use

- an inch is about 2.5 cm - it's a useful term, and easier to say than the [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) equivalent.
- *miles* has come to mean *far*.
- while few people know how many grams an ounce is, the saying still has currency because the relationship is relatively clear. An ounce is obviously much smaller than a pound.
- again, few people know how a penny or a pound relate to dollars and cents, but the meaning of the saying is clear.

It was uncommon to use terms like

- leagues
- links
- slugs

and only leagues has survived in any way, due to folk lore sayings such as *[seven league boots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-league_boots)*.

So fear not. Some sayings will endure, and some will be adapted by the population, and some will be invented. As you imply, the ones that are in use in the future will be those that are easy to use and understand.

I don't hear people in Australia saying *[the whole nine yards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_whole_nine_yards)*. If we want a picturesque way of saying *everything* we might say *the whole Hog*. They are not completely interchangeable.

As a final note, an American fast food chain sells a product here, called a "foot-long". No one has had any trouble understanding how big that is, despite the target demographic all being born after the demise of the foot.

Comment: Note that "Penny wise, pound foolish" is metric now that a pound sterling contains 100 pence.

Comment: @David: A pence is not a penny.

Comment: @Robusto Huh? "Pence" is the plural of "penny". There is no such thing as "a pence".

Comment: I just mean the pre-decimal penny was different from the new one. The old penny could be divided, etc.

Comment: “the demise of the foot” Heh. The “-long” in “foot-long” makes it make sense even if “foot” was never used as a unit of measure. As long as people still have feet at the end of their legs.

Comment: @RobertFisher It makes the expression parseable, but unless you have really long feet you might be surprised to find how large your foot-long sandwich was.

Comment: I've heard Penny Wise, Pound Foolish in America, who never used a currency called the Pound but instead uses it as a weight measure! I don't think changing to decimal pennies has a bearing on the phrase

Comment: @Yamikuronue To the contrary, the US of America used to be British and used British currency such as the pound at one time.

Comment: The Australian "half-foot" version of the "foot-long" item that @andy256 referenced is actually called the "six-inch".  So there are still idiomatic uses of imperial terms in use in this country, despite most people using metric in everyday life.

Comment: People still use imperial measurements colloquially for human height. Eyewitness reports often describe people as 183cm tall, which seems implausibly precise until you realise that what they must have said was "6 foot".

Comment: @Robusto the new penny could be divided too when there was a half a pence coin! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfpenny_%28British_decimal_coin%29

Answer (score 2):

Canadian perspective...we've been metric since before I was born, however my parents were using imperial prior.  Gives us this weird hybrid system...I know my personal weight in pounds, not kilo's...but I do buy my fruit and veggies by kg.  I use the term mileage and know my fuel consumption in miles per galleon, but I purchase fuel in litres.  Ya, it's a bit messed...my pregnant sister knows how many pounds and ounces her baby is expected to be.

To your question - there really isn't any replacement in metric.  As metric replaced imperial units, imperial units became less of an exact amount and more of a 'fuzzy' amount.  If you are travelling an exact distance, lets say 8.2 kilometers...well then I use Kilometers.  When I'm travelling a large inexact distance, then I'm travelling for miles and miles.  A fence is either one meter high, or a few feet.  Gallons refer to an estimated amount of liquid, where 4 litres refers to an exact amount

I imagine as imperial phases out, you will see the 'exact' value of the unit to become fuzzier and fuzzier and only refer to generalizations of what it once used to mean (I think that's the basis of many idioms)...which makes my answer to your question, there is no replacement for these idioms and they will that way until the people who once knew what the term meant pass on and the next generation continues.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some idioms from Dutch:

- millimeter voor millimeter = millimetre by millimetre
- centimeter voor centimeter = centimetre by centimetre
- kilometers ver / weg / ver weg = kilometres away

For fun, I have looked at sandwich sizes, but every chain uses its own terms.

And although we have plenty of sayings regarding theory and practice, none involve weight.

A lot of old measurements have been metricated, e.g. 1 pond (‘pound’) = ½ kg.

- ieder pondje komt door 't mondje = every pound comes through your mouth = taste makes waist

And then there are fossils like:

- duimstok = thumb (i.e. inch) stick = carpenter's ruler (alternative: maatstok = measure stick)

But most of these are rare. A lot of people don't know what a ‘duimstok’ is, or know it as ‘maatstok’. Of those who do know, many don't know why it is called that.

On the whole, non-metric units are very rare in daily parlance, the two most notable exceptions are inches in computing and (the misuse of) calories in food (which are actually kilocalories).

(Feel free to edit this post to add examples.)